# Find Element with directive

Tags: angular

Hello I have been searching for this for quite sometime and I cannot figure this out. So let me explain the problem, I have multiple controls that I need to add validation messages to and i would only like to create one directive to do this.

With all of that said, I am gong to create a small example of what I'm trying to accomplish and what I've tried to do.

I have a control that may look like:

```
<div class="form-group>
    <label>{{label}}</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value"/>
</div>
```

and its selector may look like: `<textbox validation controlTypeToAddValidationTo="input" label="name"></textbox>`

I have created a directive that looks like:

```
@Directive({    selector:'validation' }) 
export class ControlValidation implements OnInit{

    @Input() controlTypeToAddToolTipTo:string;
    constructor(
       private elementRef:ElementRef,
       private render:Render2
    ){}

    ngOnInit():void{
        //TODO add a tooltip to say hello to the input.
    } 
}
```

Okay, so we now have a directive but my issue is that I would like to access the input and I would like to use something like the jQuery approach where I do `$('input')` but I don't know how to do that from the directive. I would like to be able to pass in if I want to add the tooltip to an input or button or div or whatever.

So I've tried
1. `this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('input')` but it doesn't return the children.
2. `this.render.selectRootElemet('nativeElement')` it returns the first textbox element
3. `this.render.nextSibling(this.elementRef);` it returns undefined

Okay now for my question, How can I select the item that I want inside the elementRef?

Comment: If you use it on an input, it is `elementRef.nativeElement`. If you use use it on something else, you should be able to get it with `elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input')`, provided that this element has an input in it.

Comment: If you want more explanation or a working case, please provide a [mcve] reproducing this issue and all the cases you could encounter.

Comment: thank you that did it. I will also read that!